# In Cypher, how to get the count of objects directly related to it, divided by label?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a graph constructed from dependency data. I have Owners of type SCHEMA (I.e, thy have a label :SCHEMA) which have :OWNS relations to adjacent objects. I can easily get at those as follows:

```
match (schema:SCHEMA {name:"Some Schema"})-[:OWNS]->(referencedObject) return count(referencedObject)
```

The referencedObject(s) have various labels indicating their type. What I would like to do is get the count of objects per label (note: I have about 44 labels). Like:

```
BARLABEL: 100 objects
FOOLABEL: 120 objects
(etc)
```

Any pointers much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

If the referencedObject has only one label per node:

```
match (schema:SCHEMA {name:"Some Schema"})-[:OWNS]->(referencedObject)
RETURN distinct(labels(referencedObject)) as label,count(*) as count
```

Comment: They actually have two labels (always): One generic label, called ENTITY and an extra label specifying the type of the object. Your query works, however in my result set I get [ENTITY,SOMELABEL]. Obviously not an issue, I'm actually very happy this works so easily :-). But would be pretty cool if I could filter the ENTITY label out.

Answer (score 0):

With a great pointer in the right direction from Tomaž Bratanič, I managed to do this for all :SCHEMA nodes, and I also managed to filter out a generic label from the result set by modifying the query as follows:

```
MATCH (schema:SCHEMA)-[:OWNS]->(referencedObject)
RETURN DISTINCT schema.name AS schema, 
filter(x IN (labels(referencedObject)) WHERE NOT x="ENTITY") AS label, 
count(*) AS count 
ORDER BY schema,label
```